# Find Employees With Multiple Managers Listed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

We outsourced a project and are paying for it!  In our table which holds roughly 1500 employees a manager is assigned, but some employees have duplicate managers assigned.  How can I using SQL Server 2008 R2 return only each employee who has more than 1 manager assigned (so query window should return the employee and both managers assigned)?

Sample DDL to show table structure and how bad it is messed up atm

```
Create Table #DuplicationIdentifier
(
  empName varchar(500)
  ,empID varchar(25)
  ,managerID varchar(25)
)

Insert Into #DuplicationIdentifier VALUES
('Blue Bell', 'bb12', 'fj12')
,('Joe Jones', 'jj30','bb41')
,('Mark Jones', 'mj91','ll98')
,('Surge Drink', 'sd22','ll98')
,('Paul Pills', 'pp23', 'ss10')
,('Red Color', 'rc84','ss10')
,('Pink Flamingo', 'pf04','bb41')
,('Blue Bell', 'bb12','bb41')
,('Joe Jones', 'jj30','ss10')
,('Red Color', 'rc84', 'rd22')
,('Pink Flamingo', 'pf04','fj12')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach

```
WITH DuplicateManagers
AS (
    SELECT empid
        ,count(*) AS rcount
    FROM #DuplicationIdentifier
    GROUP BY empid
    HAVING count(*) > 1
    )
SELECT a.empid
    ,a.managerid
FROM #DuplicationIdentifier a
JOIN DuplicateManagers b ON b.empid = a.empID
ORDER BY a.empid
```

Answer (score 2):

You can include the counts in the details:

```
SELECT
  empid,
  managerid,
  managercount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY empid)
FROM
  #DuplicationIdentifier
```

then filter the rows on *managercount*:

```
WITH
  counted AS
  (
    SELECT
      empid,
      managerid,
      managercount = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY empid)
    FROM
      #DuplicationIdentifier
  )
SELECT
  empid,
  managerid
FROM
  counted
WHERE
  managercount > 1
;
```

The approach is fundamentally the same as in [Scott Hodgin's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149413/6965). Instead of an ordinary COUNT this variation uses a [window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) COUNT, which gives you opportunity to avoid a join.